# Trying to access an XML node value from a table column using query in SQL Server and it always returns an empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Have a table called `UserRequest` and one column of the is  XML type (column name is `RequestXML`). The values in `RequestXML` will be something like this:

```
<MyRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <transfer>
        <Field>
            <fieldId>12323</fieldId>
            <FieldDetails>
                <RequestInfoField>
                    <requestDecs>Test</requestDecs>
                    <reqDate>01/01/2021</reqDate>
                </RequestInfoField>
                <identifierKey>45638</identifierKey>
            </FieldDetails>
        </Field>
    </transfer>
</MyRequest>
```

Using the following SQL query to retrieve the XML node value of `identifierKey`, but the query is always returning an empty string :

```
select 
    T.RequestXML.query('MyRequest/transfer/Field/FieldDetails/identifierKey') As identifierKey, * 
from UserRequest  T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared your (default) namespace in your SQL:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/')
SELECT UR.RequestXML.query('MyRequest/transfer/Field/FieldDetails/identifierKey') As identifierKey,
       *
FROM dbo.UserRequest UR;
```

If you, however, explicitly want the value of `identifierKey` use `value`, not `query`.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/')
SELECT UR.RequestXML.value('(MyRequest/transfer/Field/FieldDetails/identifierKey)[1]','int') AS identifierKey
       *
FROM dbo.UserRequest UR;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=62853ae37ff87b9593ba4db0c036c55c)

Comment: If the xml file having both xsi and xsd prefixes , then the query is failing  to return any results (thexmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

Comment: Seems like you have a new question, @Libin , so should be posting a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
declare @doc xml = '<MyRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <transfer>
        <Field>
            <fieldId>12323</fieldId>
            <FieldDetails>
                <RequestInfoField>
                    <requestDecs>Test</requestDecs>
                    <reqDate>01/01/2021</reqDate>
                </RequestInfoField>
                <identifierKey>45638</identifierKey>
            </FieldDetails>
        </Field>
    </transfer>
</MyRequest>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/')
SELECT T.RequestXML.value('(/MyRequest/transfer/Field/FieldDetails/identifierKey)[1]','int') As identifierKey,  *
FROM (values(@doc)) T(RequestXML);
```